# When is a `static thread_local` global variable useful?

Tags: c++, static, thread-safety

Some codebases like [skia](https://github.com/google/skia/blob/main/src/sksl/SkSLPool.cpp#L21) define a `static thread_local` global variable. What is the point of having this as opposed to just a `thread_local` variable at a `namespace` scope?

```cpp
// From: https://github.com/google/skia/blob/main/src/sksl/SkSLPool.cpp
namespace SkSL {
  static thread_local MemoryPool* sMemPool = nullptr;
  static MemoryPool* get_thread_local_memory_pool() {
      return sMemPool;
  }

  static void set_thread_local_memory_pool(MemoryPool* memPool) {
      sMemPool = memPool;
  }

}
```

What will happen if we remove `static`.

Comment: `sMemPool` is a namespace scoped `thread_local` variable with internal linkage.  So it can only be directly used by code in this compilation unit.  Removing the `static` gives it external linkage.